# how to get 1 record of each value

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I need to get record of each TypV where ExpTime is bigger then 2017-05-24

Sample data:

```
PHVal TypV  WTemp   ExpTime
----------------------------------
 3.00   A   22.00   2017-03-29 02:34:00
 6.00   A   45.00   2017-06-29 02:34:00
 8.22   A   12.00   2017-08-25 01:25:00
 3.00   A   22.00   2017-03-29 02:34:00
11.00   B   11.00   2016-06-29 02:34:00
 1.22   C   12.00   2017-04-25 11:25:00
17.00   B    1.70   2017-05-30 02:44:00
27.22   C   76.00   2017-07-25 08:21:00
11.00   B   18.30   2017-09-29 14:34:00
27.22   C   32.00   2017-11-12 11:31:00
```

If i run SQL query

```
SELECT 
 PHVal, TypV,   WTemp,  ExpTime
FROM tempsurvey
WHERE 
 ExpTime > to_date('2017-05-24')
```

I've get several record of each TypV but I've desired output:

```
PHVal TypV  WTemp   ExpTime
----------------------------------
 6.00   A   45.00   2017-06-29 02:34:00
17.00   B    1.70   2017-05-30 02:44:00
27.22   C   76.00   2017-07-25 08:21:00
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` to get one record per group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope you want the rows which having `ExpTime > '2017-05-24'` and select one which have the minimum date for each `TypV`.

**Query**

```
select t2.PHVal,
t2.TypV,
t2.WTemp,
t2.ExpTime
from
(
   select PHVal,
   TypV,
   WTemp,
   ExpTime,
   ( 
      case TypV 
      when @curA
      then @curR := @curR + 1 
      else @curR := 1 and @curA := TypV end
   ) + 1 as rn
  from (
      select * from `your_table_name` 
      where cast(ExpTime as date) > '2017-05-24'
 ) t,
 (select @curR := 0, @curA := '') r
 order by TypV, ExpTime
)t2
where t2.rn = 1
order by TypV;
```

**[Find demo here](http://rextester.com/VIVQ90910)**

Comment: Thanks @Wanderer for help